# How do I search for available packages from the command-line?

Tags: command-line, apt

I have successfully installed some packages using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install packagename
```

when I have known in advance that those packages are available.  But how can I search for or get a list of what is available in the repositories?

Answer (score 1054, accepted):

#### To search for a particular package by name or description:

From the command-line, use:

```
apt-cache search keyword
```

where the search keyword can be all or part of a package name or any words used in its description.

For example, `apt-cache search proxy` includes both these packages:

```
tinyproxy - A lightweight, non-caching, optionally anonymizing HTTP proxy
tircd - ircd proxy to the twitter API
```

> Note: the list may be long, so you can pipe the output to `less` to make it scrollable one line or one screen at a time, i.e. `apt-cache search something | less`.

#### To get a list of ALL packages

```
apt-cache search .
```

---

#### Use Synaptic if you have X-forwarding enabled or are on a desktop

*Synaptic* is often a more convenient way to do this, but requires at least an X server on your end (unless you're running a desktop environment). Install with `sudo apt-get install synaptic` if necessary.

- Synaptic on ssh'd server via X forwarding:

  [image]
- Synaptic running locally on Ubuntu Desktop:

  [image]

Comment: @MarkThomas Try `apt-cache policy` too, it gives you more information about the sources.

Comment: like `apt-get`, you can just run `apt-cache` without any arguments and get the short help/cheatsheet info. You can always read the manpages on it for longer help. (i.e. `man apt-cache` )

Comment: Supposing that I'm foolish enough to want to live the results into `apt install`, is there a smart way to do that? The output from this function is messy. One could use the first word from each line, but there should be an easier way.

Comment: you can also search online. https://packages.ubuntu.com/

Comment: If you only need the names of all the packages available just do `apt-cache pkgnames`

Comment: Doesnt this only return cached stuff??

Answer (score 92):

Using `aptitude`, `apt-cache`, and `apt` all format the output differently. (None of these require the use of `sudo` when searching for a package.) I prefer using `apt` for its readability. It highlights the package name and puts a space between the different packages. It also has `[installed]` listed next to each package that is already installed. Usage:

```
apt search keyword
```

Comment: if i run say '$ apt search firefox' it produces tons of output results :(

Comment: You could narrow your search with something like: `apt search firefox | grep -A 3 firefox`

Comment: Another option to narrow the search: `apt search ^firefox` or `apt search ^firefox$`

Comment: @jbrock if your output is not a tty but a pipe like in `apt search firefox | grep -A 3 firefox` then you should use `apt-cache search` instead. The output of the `apt` tool is meant for human consumption and can change without notice. The `apt-get` and `apt-cache` tools have stable output that can be used in scripts and pipelines like yours.

Comment: @user3804598 true, a better option is `apt list firefox`

Answer (score 29):

You can also use aptitude from the command line:

```
aptitude search xxxxxx
```

Comment: The annoying thing about this one is that Ubuntu doesn't seem to give it to you by default. Up until I learnt about `apt-cache`, I was always having do so `apt-get install aptitude` on each new box I installed. However, since I can't find a way to get `apt-cache` to show me whether it's installed, I guess I'll have to keep doing that for a bit :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Just create two line shell script  (second line someting like `dpkg --list | grep "$1"`) or add shell function to this effect into your `.bash_login`...  :-)

Answer (score 10):

The `apt-cache` command line tool is used for searching `apt`'s software package cache. In simple words, this tool is used to search software packages, collect information about packages and also search for what packages are available and ready for installation on Debian- or Ubuntu-based systems.

To find a package's name along with its description before installing, use the `search` flag. Using `search` with `apt-cache` will display a list of matched packages with a short description.

The general syntax of `apt-cache search` is:

```
apt-cache search SearchTerm
```

where `SearchTerm` is the term you wish to search for. For example, let’s say you would like to find the description of the `vsftpd` package. The command you would use would be:

```
apt-cache search vsftpd
```

The possible output would be:

```
vsftpd - lightweight, efficient FTP server written for security
ccze - A robust, modular log coloriser
ftpd - File Transfer Protocol (FTP) server
yasat - simple stupid audit tool
```

To find and list down all the packages starting with `vsftpd`, you
could use the following command.

```
apt-cache pkgnames vsftpd
```

You may also want to run the results through `more` or even `grep` commands. For instance:

```
apt-cache search firefox | grep plugin
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Assuming you want to do all of this from the terminal use the following:

first I recommend you update the package index files so the list of all files in the repository you are about to create is up to date

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then use "**search** regex" function in `apt-cache` where "regex" stands for Regular Expression and is the pattern given to search. For more info about search patterns you can look up manual regex(7) by command `man 7 regex` or in [English](http://www.aboutlinux.info/2006/01/learn-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html). A **regex** variable equal to  **.**  will suffice.

```
apt-cache search .
```

The above will give you ALL the results but it is not in any order that is particularly helpful for browsing.

**So finally we can sort by dictionary order using`sort -d` and show only a page at a time using`less`.**

```
apt-cache search . |sort -d |less
```

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to add this a comment on the main answer.

But I was trying to find `g++-` - alike packages with `apt-cache search`. It's important to know in this case that `keyword` *is a regular expression* so `apt-cache search g++-` will not have helpful results.

`apt-cache search "g[+][+][-]"` would be the way to go

Answer (score 6):

`apt list <package>` is how I recommend searching for packages. If you don't get any matches or if you're not sure what the package is named, try wrapping the argument in asterisks to get more results. For instance `apt list *chrome*` will yield the following:

```
Listing...
chrome-gnome-shell/focal,focal,now 10.1-5 all
chromium-chromedriver/focal-updates 1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64
chromium-lwn4chrome/focal,focal 1.0-3 all
google-chrome-beta/stable 99.0.4844.17-1 amd64
google-chrome-stable/stable,now 98.0.4758.80-1 amd64
google-chrome-unstable/stable 100.0.4867.0-1 amd64
mkchromecast-alsa/focal,focal 0.3.8.1-1 all
mkchromecast-gstreamer/focal,focal 0.3.8.1-1 all
mkchromecast-pulseaudio/focal,focal 0.3.8.1-1 all
mkchromecast/focal,focal 0.3.8.1-1 all
node-chrome-trace-event/focal,focal 1.0.2-1 all
openchrome-tool/focal 1:0.6.0-3build1 amd64
python3-pychromecast/focal,focal 4.1.0-1 all
ruby-chromedriver-helper/focal,focal 2.1.0-7 all
xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-openchrome/focal 1:0.6.0-3build1 amd64
```

Alternatively, if you'd like a description of each package, run `apt search --names-only <package>`. Make sure to include `--names-only` for more accurate results.

Answer (score 1):

The OP aimed only to `apt`, which was already answered (`apt search`). Some people might end up here searching for solutions for other (more modern) alternatives.

Nowadays we have other sources for apps: [`pip`](https://pypi.org/project/pip/), [`brew`](https://brew.sh/), [`flatpak`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1384366/349837) and [`npm`](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started), to name a few popular ones. All of them also works with **`search`** subcommand.

You could handle all of the above and others with [`meta-package-manager`](https://pypi.org/project/meta-package-manager/), which solves [XKCD #1654](https://xkcd.com/1654/) (don't look [#927](https://xkcd.com/927/)).

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-file search part_of_package_name
```

"Extended variant" is useful in case of excessive number of results:

```
apt-file search part_of_package_name | grep another_part_of_name
```

Example of searching for ssh server package if I do not know the name is ssh-server or sshserver or server-ssh etc.:

```
apt-file search ssh | grep server
```

Steps to prepare `apt-file search` for searching. It should be done before first usage:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```