# Exclude package installation to resolve conflict

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, software-installation

when I try to install a package by doing

```
apt-get install abc*
```

it gives me an error between two packages that

```
abc-x : | Conflicts: abc-y
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I would like to exclude abc-x from the regex of my initial command. Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/216995/2268345?

Comment: I looked at that before, but I could not figure out how to use it in an apt-get command. Because I want all abc* except abc-x.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**

Create a package-list with

`apt-cache search abc*>package-list`

source: [How do I search for available packages from the command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160897/how-do-i-search-for-available-packages-from-the-command-line)

**Step 2**

Install the packages with

`cat package-list | xargs sudo apt-get install`

source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1548121