# How to find which Ubuntu repo a package belongs to

Tags: apt, package-management, gcc

Long story short, I want to install gcc, but it gave me errors, and I found it resulted in:

```
Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12 is to be installed
```

I have tried to downgrade my gcc-5-base, which was absolutely a BAD IDEA.

So planned to change the repo in the source.list to the gcc candidate which depends on `5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12`.

I found one on this website: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-5/5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12, but I don't know how to find the corresponding Ubuntu repo.

Comment: replaced some of entries in my source.list by referring to this git: https://gist.github.com/rohitrawat/60a04e6ebe4a9ec1203eac3a11d4afc1, everything is fine now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps using rmadison can help, e.g.

```
rmadison gcc
 gcc | 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5   | precise         | amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 gcc | 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6   | trusty          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 gcc | 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1   | xenial          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 gcc | 4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2   | bionic          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 gcc | 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3 | bionic-security | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 gcc | 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3 | bionic-updates  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 gcc | 4:8.3.0-1ubuntu3   | disco           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 gcc | 4:9.2.1-3.1ubuntu1 | eoan            | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 gcc | 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2   | focal           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 gcc | 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2   | groovy          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x

or:
madison gcc-9
 gcc-9 | 9-20190402-1ubuntu1  | disco          | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 gcc-9 | 9.1.0-2ubuntu2~19.04 | disco-security | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 gcc-9 | 9.1.0-2ubuntu2~19.04 | disco-updates  | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 gcc-9 | 9.2.1-9ubuntu2       | eoan           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 gcc-9 | 9.3.0-10ubuntu2      | focal          | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 gcc-9 | 9.3.0-13ubuntu1      | groovy         | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! I cant apt install madison. Is it because my source list is wrong? It seems like the repo url is my companies one, is there any way to find a default source list for ubuntu?

Comment: Info: The `rmadison` command is provided by the `devscripts` package.