# How to fix 'acroread' not starting on Ubuntu 20.04.4?

Tags: 20.04, adobe

I have been trying to install manually Adobe Reader 9 mutiple times on Ubuntu 20.04.4, but the app does not start. When I type in a terminal

```
acroread some_file.pdf
```

I get the following output but nothing more. No errors, no warnings, and under `ps -ef` there is no job named `acroread`.

How can I try to fix this problem?

Here is the complete but meaningless output:

```
(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.691: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.691: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.692: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.692: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.693: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.693: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.693: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.693: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.693: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.693: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.693: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.693: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.693: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.694: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.694: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.694: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.694: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.694: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.694: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.694: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.694: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(acroread:17581): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:35:23.695: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
```

I tried to install

```
sudo apt install gtk2-engines-pixbuf
```

but it seems it was already installed, and did not change anything.

Comment: Is there a reason to use such old software? Is there something wrong/missing with the default native PDF reader or the other dozen or so?

Comment: Have you tried to run `evince`? It has been working way better than `acroread` for several years now...

Comment: Yes ok, I will use evince. I was not aware that adobe abandoned Linux.

Comment: ChanganAuto yes https://askubuntu.com/questions/471561/how-to-view-3d-pdf-files i cannot post a comment

Comment: @ChanganAuto Only Acro reader supports session restore, a feature dearly missed on all these crappy PDF readers on Linux