# How to find the name of an app from Ubuntu Software

Tags: software-installation, 16.04

I want to install my apps by `apt-get install` from terminal but there aren't any options to get an app name in Ubuntu Software. What can I do?

Comment: Can you give examples of software packages you're looking at?

Comment: Virtualbox, vlc, gimp, etc.

Comment: And to be clear: You find an app in Ubuntu Software and you want to install it with apt-get in terminal?  In that case, you can type `sudo apt-get install` and part of the name, like `virtualb` and press TAB to see packages that match.

Comment: try this website: http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

I usually google for the apt installation instructions for what I am looking for.

But I will usually start looking for the app in the Ubuntu Software app on my machine, and only go to apt if I can't find it there first. (this is of course from a desktop install)

So, for instance, if I google "apt install samba" I get several pages, I then read them to find the one I like, and then try the commands given.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to search packages info in "**Synaptic Package Manager**".  It has been the default package manager for many years, and you can install it from "Software"/"Software manager", just search for Synaptic, or try `sudo apt-get install synaptic`.

It has a powerful search function that will find packages by their names or by their functionallity (i.e. you search for text editor and it list a huge list of related packages).  It can also be used to know the package name of some already installed software, when you want to run them from command line, for example to run something with specific parameters or with root permissions.  (For example "sudo gedit", to save and edit text based config files)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your package manager (works for both [`apt`](https://wiki.debian.org/Apt), [`aptitude`](https://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude)), you can do this from the terminal

```bsh
apt search package-name
```

Or you could further format and filter down results like this:

```bsh
apt search firefox | grep -A 3 firefox
```

**See Also**: [How do I search for available packages from the command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/160897/349745)