# software centre: search apps from the terminal?

Tags: software-center

i'd prefer not to see a large advertisement for "spotify" every time i open the software centre

is it possible to disable the "featured application" and "editor's picks"? A search online reveals nothing and i suspect then it's not possible

therefore, is it possible to search the software centre from the terminal? an online search for this question also revealed nothing

edit: I am using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: You've not provided any OS & release details; but the software centre from most releases handles both *snap* and *deb* packages, so requires two commands... ie. `apt search` to look for *deb* packages, and `snap search` to search or *snap* packages.. If you're using a *flavor* & using another store; you'll need more than just those commands as well (eg. Software Boutique searches outside of just those two)

Answer (score 1):

To search for software from the terminal:

- See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160897/how-do-i-search-for-available-packages-from-the-command-line) on how to find packages available as .deb packages.
- Use `snap search <string>` to search packages available in snap format.

Comment: excellent, thanks. I tried "snap search pycharm" as an example, it revealed what i needed