# Ubuntu Server - NGINX, MongoDB, NPM and PM2 costs?

Tags: upgrade

I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu.

I'm looking some software to add on into the OS like:

- Mongodb
- Node 12.18.1
- Npm 6.14.4
- Nginx 1.17.10
- Pm2 4.4.0

Is the above applications free or chargeable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I search for available packages from the command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160897/how-do-i-search-for-available-packages-from-the-command-line)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, most applications are open-source and free. You can either boot an existing Ubuntu and use `apt` to search for packages, or use the [online package library to search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/). If you find the packages here, they can be installed for free.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of it depends on which version you are using. Take for example NGINX - there is the open-source version of [NGINX](https://nginx.org/en/) and [NGINX Plus](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/) which does have some cost for a license/support. I would say it is a fairly safe assumption that most packages included in GNU/Linux based distros are going to the be free and or open-source versions.

A couple of quick Google searches could have yielded the results you were looking for:

- MongoDB - [Does not appear to have a cost, since Ubuntu is using the community version.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)
- NPM - [Same goes for NPM.](https://techpiezo.com/nodejs/install-npm-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts/)
- NGINX - [Is also using the open-source community version.](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-nginx#2-installing-nginx)
- PM2 - [Does appear to have a cost, but I am also assuming that NPM is going to install the open-source version.](https://pm2.io/pricing)

So TL;DR essentially there is some cost with some of the software you plan on using, but using the distribution provided versions is most likely not going to cost anything.

Hope this helps.