# "Unable to locate package" errors when trying to remove Thunderbird mail

Tags: apt, software-installation, thunderbird

I am trying to delete Thunderbird mail since I primarily use Gmail in the browser. However, on trying to remove it I'm getting the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove Thunderbird Mail
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package Thunderbird
E: Unable to locate package Mail
```

Comment: Thunderbird is default a snap.  Use `sudo snap remove thunderbird`.

Comment: hi. thanks for your quick reply buddy....i tried it but i am getting the following resultean@jean-desktop:~$ sudo snap remove thunderbird
snap "thunderbird" is not installed

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1504499/edit) to include the complete output of `whereis thunderbird` and of `which thunderbird`. How you uninstall software depends upon which kind of package (if any) was used to install it. There is no single all-software command.

Comment: If it's installed as a deb-package, use `sudo apt remove thunderbird`.

Comment: Thanks, mook 765 it worked, i was using sudo apt-get remove thunderbird instead

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [@mook765's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1504499/removing-thunderbird-mail#comment2639322_1504499) is the solution for your issue:

> If it's installed as a deb-package, use `sudo apt remove thunderbird`.

However, [based on your comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1504499/removing-thunderbird-mail#comment2639324_1504499), your understanding about why this command worked is not correct (formatting and some text fixes my own):

> Thanks mook765, it worked. I was using `sudo apt-get remove thunderbird` instead.

You see, `sudo apt remove thunderbird` and `sudo apt-get remove thunderbird` should have both worked. After all, `apt` is more or less a front-end for `apt-get`, as you can read in [What is the difference between apt and apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/q/445384/618353) What this means is that when you run `sudo apt remove <package>`, `sudo apt-get remove <package>` is run behind the scenes.

Then, you may ask, why were you getting `Unable to locate package` errors? The answer is in your question: You were not running `sudo apt-get remove thunderbird`, but `sudo apt-get remove Thunderbird Mail` instead. To make it more clear, you were trying to remove Thunderbird by providing the program's name (`Thunderbird Mail`) instead of the package's name, which is `thunderbird`.

Additionally, the reason why you were getting two `Unable to locate package` errors is because `apt` and `apt-get` expect each package to be a single string, without spaces. Spaces are used to separate packages, since `apt` and `apt-get` accept multiple packages as arguments. So when you were running `sudo apt-get remove Thunderbird Mail`, `apt-get` was trying to find and uninstall a package named `Thunderbird`, but couldn't find it (it's case sensitive), so you got the first `Unable to locate package` error, and then was trying to find the package `Mail`, which also couldn't find, so you got the second `Unable to locate package` error.

If you want to know how to find the package name of a program, you may have a look at [How do I search for available packages from the command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/160897/618353), from which I recommend [@jbrock's suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/854382/618353) for using:

```
apt search keyword
```

where `keyword` is usually a part of the program's name.